# Multiple range inputs synchronized, giving always the same sum

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm trying to create a page where I can divide a given amount, for a variable number of persons. The sum of that division must always be the same and equal to the initial value.

I'm facing a lot of difficulties, since range input on AngularJS always returns a string so I have to convert it to float, then multiply it by 100, so I can do calculations without facing the floating point precision problems.

Another problem is when the division between the persons is not precise, like 100€ / 3, it will give 33,3333(3). What I ideally want to do is something like this: 33,33 + 33,33 + 33,34.

Related to the problem before, sometimes I'm getting values with more than 2 decimals places.

You can find a working example, in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/FabioAntunes/pen/WvORpB), where when one range input is changed, all the other ones update in the inverse way (When I increase one, the others must decrease and vice versa).

**Note**: The range inputs don't work by click and dragging you must click on the position you want(they are for touching devices), also you can only move them when "equal amount" is disabled.

The controller code is here:

```
angular.module('ionicApp')   
.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.stuff = {
    persons: [],
    max: 100,
    equal: true

  };

  $scope.addPerson = function(){
    var person = {
      expenseValue: 0   
    };

    $scope.stuff.persons.push(person);
    $scope.recalcTotal(-1);
  };

  $scope.recalcTotal = function(index){
    var i = 0;
    var length = $scope.stuff.persons.length;

    if($scope.stuff.equal){

      var equalExpense = $scope.stuff.max / length;

      for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        $scope.stuff.persons[i].expenseValue = equalExpense;
      }

    }else if(index > 0){
      var total = 0;
      var delta = 0;
      var i = 0;


      for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        $scope.stuff.persons[i].expenseValue = parseFloat($scope.stuff.persons[i].expenseValue) * 100;
        total += $scope.stuff.persons[i].expenseValue;
      }

      delta = ($scope.stuff.max * 100 - total)/length;


        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          if(i !== index){
            $scope.stuff.persons[i].expenseValue = _calcNewValue(delta, $scope.stuff.persons[index].expenseValue, $scope.stuff.persons[i].expenseValue);
          }
        }
        $scope.stuff.persons[index].expenseValue = $scope.stuff.persons[index].expenseValue / 100;
      }
  };

  function _calcNewValue(delta, value, userExpense){

    var newValue =  userExpense + delta;


    if (newValue < 0 || value === $scope.stuff.max * 100){
      newValue = 0;
    }
    else if (newValue > $scope.stuff.max * 100){
      newValue = $scope.stuff.max * 100;
    }

    return newValue / 100;
  }
});
```